# How to read data from service before app loads in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular5

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 5. I am trying to load below component in app.module.ts.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    AppInsightsModule.forRoot(???)
    ],
    declarations: [
    AppComponent],
    providers: [
     ConfigurationService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (config: ConfigurationService) => () => config.GetAppSettings(),
        deps: [ConfigurationService],
        multi: true
    }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
export class AppModule {
    public configData: any;
    constructor(configProvider: ConfigurationService)
    {
        configProvider.GetAppSettings().then(result => {
            this.configData = JSON.stringify(result.ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey);
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to read data for the instruentationkey from appsettings.json. In the constructor I am able to call service and get data successfully. When I add

```
  AppInsightsModule.forRoot(this.configData)
```

I am getting this.configData is undefined. I want to load data to instrumentationkey from the appsettings.json. So can someone help me to figure out the way to above work correctly? Any help help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you call   `AppInsightsModule.forRoot(this.configData)`in the `then`closure or just below on the constructor ?

Comment: inside the then closure. I just added my constructor above